# SQL stored procedure throwing invalid in the select list error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by

I am converting from mysql to sql server.

While converting a select stored proc,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE selPropertyByAcntID
(
@in_acntID INT
)
AS
SELECT *
     , SUM(CASE
                        WHEN u.prop_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                 END) AS UnitCount
FROM 
    prop_details d
INNER JOIN 
    acnt_property a
ON 
    d.prop_id = a.prop_id
LEFT JOIN 
    unit_details u
ON 
    d.prop_id = u.prop_id
WHERE 
    a.group_id = @in_acntID
GROUP BY 
    d.prop_id;
```

It is throwing the following error:

Error: 8120 Severity 16
Column 'prop_details.prop_title' is invalid in the select list because it is not container in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

strange -- the exact same stored proc isworking in a mysql environment.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server and just about every RDBMS **except** MySQL you can only include in the `SELECT` list items that are included in the `GROUP BY` list or those wrapped in an aggregate.

So to resolve the issue get rid of `*`, select only the columns you need from tables `d` and `a` and add this list also to the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, not related to your question. This part:

```
 , SUM(CASE
              WHEN u.prop_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
              ELSE 0
       END) AS UnitCount
```

can be simplified to:

```
 , COUNT(u.prop_id) AS UnitCount
```

Comment: Hi ypercube, i tried that but it returned only a single data set with the count vs, the complete data set even when COUNT = 0.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server (I thought most RDBMS in fact...) statements with `GROUP BY` can only include the grouping columns along with aggregating functions. For example, this would work:

```
SELECT ColumnA, SUM(ColumnB) TotalCount
FROM Table
GROUP BY ColumnA;
```

But this would not:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnC, ColumnD, SUM(ColumnB) TotalCount
FROM Table
GROUP BY ColumnA;
```

Because `ColumnC` and `ColumnD` aren't being grouped.

Answer (score 0):

In you select you have `*`, but only grouping by the `prop_id`.  If you change you `*` to just be `d.prop_id` you should be good.  If you need any other columns specify them in the select and the group by.